# No se pueden enviar datos con los campos desabilitados

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo campos que son traídos de un servidor y que al momento de guardarlos, me aparecen advertencias de que debo llenar los campos de texto. Esto es muy raro, la única manera que veo para solucionar este problema es usando ViewBag, pero quiero saber si se puede de otra manera. Además, solo funciona si los campos NO ESTÁN DESABILITADOS

**ANTES:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**DESPUÉS:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VISTA:**

```
@model wsCharlas.Models.ClsInteresado

@{
                /**/

                ViewBag.Title = "Inscripción";
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Inscripción:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>Aquí usted podrá inscribirse a la charla respectiva que escogió.</h4>

    <hr />
    <strong>DATOS DEL PARTICIPANTE:</strong>
    <hr />

    <!--    <div class="form-horizontal"> -->
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dni_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dni_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_dni", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dni_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_apePat", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_apeMat", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_nombres", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_fechNac", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.edad_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.edad_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_edad", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.edad_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sexos, "Seleccione su sexo", new { @id = "campo_sexo", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_direccion", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depar_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.depar_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Departamentos, "Seleccione un Departamento", new { @id = "campo_departamento", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.depar_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.provin_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.provin_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Provincias, "Seleccione una Provincia", new { id = "campo_provincia", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.provin_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dist_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dist_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Distritos, "Seleccione un Distrito", new { @id = "campo_distrito", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dist_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_correo", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_telefono", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <strong>DATOS DE LA CHARLA:</strong>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            <!--disabled = "true" -->
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.id, } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Charla:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.titulo" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label class="control-label">Descripcion:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.descripcion" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Fecha:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.fecha" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Hora:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.hora" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <label class="control-label">Direccion:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.direccion" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {



            //$('#combo_departamento option[value="LIMA"]').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');

            //VER
            //$('#campo_departamento option:nth-child(1)').attr("value", "000");
            //$('#campo_provincia option:nth-child(1)').attr("value", "000");
            //$('#campo_distrito option:nth-child(1)').attr("value", "000");
            //VER

            //$('#campo_departamento option:nth-child(1)').attr("selected", "selected");

            /*$('#campo_departamento option').remove();
            $('#campo_departamento').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Departamento</option>");

            $('#campo_provincia option').remove();
            $('#campo_provincia').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione una Provincia</option>");

            $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
            $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");*/

            //var diaFechNac = $("#campo_fechNac").val().substring(6, 8);
            //var mesFechNac = $("#campo_fechNac").val().substring(4, 6);
            //var anioFechNac = $("#campo_fechNac").val().substring(0, 4);



        //----

            var dni = $("#campo_dni");
            var apePat = $("#campo_apePat");
            var apeMat = $("#campo_apeMat");
            var nombres = $("#campo_nombres");
            var fechNac = $("#campo_fechNac");
            var edad = $("#campo_edad");
            var sexo = $("#campo_sexo");
            var correo = $("#campo_correo");
            var telefono = $("#campo_telefono");
            var direccion = $("#campo_direccion");
            var departamento = $("#campo_departamento");
            var provincia = $("#campo_provincia");
            var distrito = $("#campo_distrito");

            apePat.prop("disabled", true);
            apeMat.prop("disabled", true);
            nombres.prop("disabled", true);
            fechNac.prop("disabled", true);

            //sexo.prop("disabled", true);

            //fechNac.val("00/00/0000");

            //HAY QUE COLOCAR AQUI UN SELECTED PARA QUE SE PUEDA LLENAR EL OTRO COMBO Y ASI SUCESIVAMENTE

            var diaNacimiento;
            var mesNacimiento;
            var anioNacimiento;

            function formInteresado() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ConsultarDNI", "Charlas")',
                data: { dni: dni.val()},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rpta) {
                    apePat.val(rpta.apePat_Inter);
                    apeMat.val(rpta.apeMat_Inter);
                    nombres.val(rpta.nombres_Inter);

                    //console.log(rpta.fecha_nac_Inter);

                    if ((rpta.fecha_nac_Inter) != null) {
                        var fechaNacimiento = rpta.fecha_nac_Inter;
                        diaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento.substring(6, 8);
                        mesNacimiento = fechaNacimiento.substring(4, 6);
                        anioNacimiento = fechaNacimiento.substring(0, 4);
                    } else {
                        diaNacimiento = "00";
                        mesNacimiento = "00";
                        anioNacimiento = "0000";
                    }

                    fechNac.val(diaNacimiento + "/" + mesNacimiento + "/" + anioNacimiento);

                    //edad.val(rpta.edad_Inter);
                    sexo.val(rpta.sexo_Inter);
                    //correo.val(rpta.correo_Inter);
                    //telefono.val(rpta.telefono_Inter);
                    direccion.val(rpta.direccion_Inter);
                    departamento.val(rpta.depar_Inter);

                    //departamento.selectedIndex = 1;
                    //$('#campo_departamento option:nth-child(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
                    provincia.val(rpta.provin_Inter);
                    distrito.val(rpta.dist_Inter);
                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        $("#campo_dni").focusout(function () {
            formInteresado();
        });

            //----------------

            function formProvincia() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ConsultarProvincias", "Charlas")',
                data: { depa: departamento.val()},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rpta) {

                    $.each(rpta, function (index, element) {
                        $("#campo_provincia").append('<option value="' + element.Text + '">' + element.Text + '</option>');
                    });

                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

            $(document).on("change", "#campo_departamento", function () {
                $('#campo_provincia option').remove();
                $('#campo_provincia').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione una Provincia</option>");

                $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
                $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");

                formProvincia();
            });

            $("#campo_departamento").change(function () {

                $('#campo_provincia option').remove();
                $('#campo_provincia').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione una Provincia</option>");

                $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
                $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");

                formProvincia();
        });

            //--------

            function formDistrito() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ConsultarDistritos", "Charlas")',
                data: { depa: departamento.val(), prov: provincia.val() },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rpta) {

                    $.each(rpta, function (index, element) {
                        $("#campo_distrito").append('<option value="' + element.Text + '">' + element.Text + '</option>');
                    });

                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

            $(document).on("change", "#campo_provincia", function () {
                $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
                $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");
                formDistrito();
            });

            $("#campo_provincia").change(function () {
                $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
                $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");
                formDistrito();
        });



    });

    //-------------

    //$("#campo_departamento").val();
    //$("#campo_provincia").val();

    /*function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres) {
        var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

        if (unicode == 8 || unicode == 46 || unicode == 13 || unicode == 9 || unicode == 37 || unicode == 39 || unicode == 38 || unicode == 40)
            return true;

        if (contenido.length >= caracteres) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function limitar2(tecla, contenido, caracteres) {
        if (tecla.charCode == 8 || tecla.charCode == 46 || tecla.charCode == 13 || tecla.charCode == 9 || tecla.charCode == 37 || tecla.charCode == 39 || tecla.charCode == 38 || tecla.charCode == 40) {
            return true;
        }

        if (contenido.length >= caracteres) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    $("#campo_dni").on("keypress", limitar2(event, $("#campo_dni").val(), 9))*/

</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/ExpresionesRegularesCharlas/regex.js"></script>
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
//Interesados
    public ActionResult CrearInteresado(string id, string titulo, string descripcion, string fecha, string hora, string direccion)
    {

        List<ClsSexo> listaSexo = new List<ClsSexo>();

        ClsSexo Sexo1 = new ClsSexo();
        Sexo1.sexo_Text = "M";
        Sexo1.sexo_Value = "M";

        ClsSexo Sexo2 = new ClsSexo();
        Sexo2.sexo_Text = "F";
        Sexo2.sexo_Value = "F";

        listaSexo.Add(Sexo1);
        listaSexo.Add(Sexo2);

        ViewBag.Sexos = new SelectList(listaSexo, "sexo_Text", "sexo_Value");

        //URGENTE => LOS DATOS DE LOS VIEWBAG SALEN EN EL BUSCADOR, SE DEBE ENCRIPTAR PORQUE SE PUEDEN CAMBIAR LOS DATOS

        //==============ENVIAR DATOS A LA VISTA==================
        ViewBag.id = id;
        ViewBag.titulo = titulo;
        ViewBag.descripcion = descripcion;
        ViewBag.fecha = fecha;
        ViewBag.hora = hora;
        ViewBag.direccion = direccion;
        //=======================================================

        ViewBag.Departamentos = new SelectList(listarDepartamentos(), "desc_dept", "desc_dept");
        ViewBag.Provincias = new SelectList(listarProvincias("000"), "desc_prov", "desc_prov");
        ViewBag.Distritos = new SelectList(listarDistritos("000", "000"), "desc_dist", "desc_dist");

        return View(new ClsInteresado());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CrearInteresado(ClsInteresado interesado)
    {

        ViewBag.Departamentos = new SelectList(listarDepartamentos(), "desc_dept", "desc_dept", interesado.depar_Inter);
        ViewBag.Provincias = new SelectList(listarProvincias("000"), "desc_prov", "desc_prov", interesado.provin_Inter);
        ViewBag.Distritos = new SelectList(listarDistritos("000", "000"), "desc_dist", "desc_dist", interesado.dist_Inter);

        List<ClsSexo> listaSexo = new List<ClsSexo>();

        ClsSexo Sexo1 = new ClsSexo();
        Sexo1.sexo_Text = "M";
        Sexo1.sexo_Value = "M";

        ClsSexo Sexo2 = new ClsSexo();
        Sexo2.sexo_Text = "F";
        Sexo2.sexo_Value = "F";

        listaSexo.Add(Sexo1);
        listaSexo.Add(Sexo2);

        ViewBag.Sexos = new SelectList(listaSexo, "sexo_Text", "sexo_Value");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.mensaje = "Datos Invalidos";
            return View(new ClsInteresado());
        }

            //ViewBag.Departamentos = new SelectList(listarDepartamentos(), "desc_dept", "desc_dept");
            //ViewBag.Provincias = new SelectList(listarProvincias("01"), "desc_prov", "desc_prov");
            //ViewBag.Distritos = new SelectList(listarDistritos("01", "01"), "desc_dist", "desc_dist");

        ViewBag.mensaje = "Datos Validos";

            ClsConexion con = new ClsConexion();
            var Cnx = con.Conexion();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SIMEXA_SP_REGISTRAR_INTERESADO", Cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_DNI", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.dni_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_Ape_pat", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.apePat_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_Ape_mat", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.apeMat_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_nombres", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.nombres_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_fech_naci", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.fecha_nac_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_edad", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.edad_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_sexo", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.sexo_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_correo", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.correo_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_telefono", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.telefono_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_direc", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.direccion_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_dept", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.depar_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_prov", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.provin_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_dist", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.dist_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_id_charla", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.ID_charla;
            Cnx.Open();

            OracleTransaction tx = Cnx.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tx.Commit();

            Cnx.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            Cnx.Dispose();

            return View(interesado);

    }
```

**CLASE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

//Directivas
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace wsCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsInteresado
    {
        public string ID_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DNI:")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d{8}", ErrorMessage = "El DNI debe tener 8 números")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su DNI")]
        public string dni_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Apellido Paterno:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su Apellido Paterno")]
        public string apePat_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Apellido Materno:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su Apellido Materno")]
        public string apeMat_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nombres:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su Nombre completo")]
        public string nombres_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Nacimiento:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su Fecha de Nacimiento")]
        public string fecha_nac_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Edad:")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d{1,2}", ErrorMessage = "Solo se aceptan números con 1 o 2 digitos")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su edad")]

        public string edad_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sexo:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione su sexo")]
        public string sexo_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Correo:")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su email")]
        public string correo_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Telefono / Celular:")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression("^(\\d{7}|\\d{9})$", ErrorMessage = "7 a 9")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su teléfono o celular")]
        public string telefono_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dirección:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su dirección")]
        public string direccion_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Departamento:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione su departamento")]
        public string depar_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Provincia:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione su provincia")]
        public string provin_Inter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Distrito:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione su distrito")]
        public string dist_Inter { get; set; }
        public string ID_charla { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: los datos en controles inhabilitados son para que el usuario no los modifique por eso te llegan vacios, ahora antes de pasar los parametros a tu SP, debes cargar nuevamente los datos --no modificables--  y pasarlos a tu SP. O modificar el SP y no solicitar esos campos no modificables.

Comment: En lugar de utilizar `disabled` utiliza `readonly`

Comment: Gracias amigo @anayarojo, coloca tu respuesta para que pueda marcarla como definitiva :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de `disabled` utiliza `readonly`

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label class="control-label">Direccion:</label>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.direccion" readonly />
    </div>
</div>
```